# Definition of null space

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, definition

I have two definitions of null space. One by Serge Lang

> Suppose that for every element $u$ of $V$ we have $\langle u,u\rangle=O$. The
>   scalar product is then said to be null, and $V$ is called a null space.

and another by David C. Lay

> The null space of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is the set of all
>   solutions of the homogeneous equation $Ax=0$.

I cannot find the relationship between these definitions. Can anybody give a hint to me?

Comment: What is $(u,u)$? Unless $V = \{0\}$, then $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is not a candidate for inner-product.

Comment: Two different mathematical concepts, same name. It happens all the time. There's not enough words for all the mathematical things we want to talk about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two things described are very different; the only "relationship" is that the term null refers to something having to do with zero, and both things are some sort of vector space.

Those who use Lang's definition of a null-space would strictly refer to the second idea (what Lay calls a "null space") as the "kernel" of a matrix.